# Need regex to find text in C#

Tags: c#, regex

This is to my deleted question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843964/need-regex-to-find-text-in-c-sharp

I have a string similar to this:

```
<Label Content="Hi"/>
<SomeControl Header ="welcome"/>
```

From the above string data, I want to get:

```
Content="Hi"
Header="welcome"
```

The regex expression can be combined or separate to get these two strings.

Before I edit the question, it got deleted. I wanted to make following edit:

By trying online regex testers, I managed to try following:

```
 Content="[^"]*")
```

But when I put the same in C# string, I get error:

```
 string expr = @"Content="[^"]*")";
```

I know that some string escape sequence needed. So wanted to find it. However I am not able to find it yet. Why I want to file such xml (XAML file) like this is I want to find number of occurrences of hard coded string. So I do not need any xml parsing or anything like that. Just plain simple regex to found count of such strings.

Comment: escape `"`s and try `string expr = @"Content=""[^""]*"")";` But as mentioned in your deleted answer. don't use regex for this...

Comment: XHTML is a subset XML: use an XML parser!

Comment: @JeffBridgman you mean XHTML? not html.

Comment: I am getting this error in C# upon compiling:
parsing "Content="[^"]*")" - Too many )'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your point.

You can definitely capture multiple results with a RegEx, when you're sure other ways aren't appropriate.   (although xml is a pretty handy format)

Did you possibly mean to use .Match**es** at the end, though?

```
string expr = @"Content=""[^""]*""";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(expr);
string data = @"<SomeControl Content=""sup""><anotherControl Content=""hey""><athird Content=""yo""></athird></anotherControl></SomeControl>"; // This will be replaced with actual file content
var res = reg.Matches(data);
var occuranceCount = res.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally following worked for me:

```
        string expr = @"Content=""[^""]*""";
        Regex reg = new Regex(expr);
        string data = @"<SomeControl Content=""Hi"">"; // This will be replaced with actual file content
        var res = reg.Match(data);
        var occuranceCount = res.Groups.Count;
```